# Derivation of polar stereographic projection

Tags: geometry, stereographic-projections, cartography

I have tried to reproduce the transformation rules when one does polar stereographic projection from [Mathworld web](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/StereographicProjection.html). Similar equations appear in [Snyder (1987)](https://pubs.er.usgs.gov/publication/pp1395).

When I do the calculation, I get (for the projection centered on the north pole):

$$
\begin{align}
  x' &= 2R \tan{\frac{\theta}{2}}\cos{\phi}\,\\
  y' &= 2R \tan{\frac{\theta}{2}}\sin{\phi}\,
\end{align}
$$

where the angles and symbols are defined below in the image. $x'$ and $y'$ axes have the same direction as the $x$ and $y$ axes. The formula from the above reference gives:

$$
\begin{align}
  x' &=  2R \frac{\cos{\theta_L}}{1+\sin{\theta_L}}\sin{(\lambda-\lambda_0)}\,\\
  y' &= -2R \frac{\cos{\theta_L}}{1+\sin{\theta_L}}\cos{(\lambda-\lambda_0)}\,,
\end{align}
$$
where according the the Mathworld "$\lambda_0$ is the central longitude" (whatever that is supposed to be) and $\theta_L = \frac\pi2 - \theta$ and with a little algebra, one can show that:

$$
\begin{align}
\tan{\frac\theta2} &= \frac{\cos{\theta_L}}{1+\sin{\theta_L}}\,.
\end{align}
$$

So the only difference is in the last terms. They suggest the relationship:

$$
\begin{align}
  \phi = \lambda - \lambda_0 - \frac\pi2\,.
\end{align}
$$

This suggests that my solution and projection is somehow rotated along the z-axis. I do not really understand the concept of $\lambda_0$ in the first place. When one browses the  catalogue file [DSMAP_POLAR.CAT](http://imbrium.mit.edu/CATALOG/DSMAP_POLAR.CAT) for the LOLA lunar mission, they use the above Mathworld equation with $\lambda_0=0$. Can someone explain why all the references have the $\sin$ instead of $\cos$ and $-\cos$ instead of $\sin$, that is why is my solution unusual (why is the common practice different)?

[image]